# Getting " Gas estimation failed" error for pet project - "smart_lottery_contract" project

Tags: transactions, gas, brownie, chainlink

I am new to blockchain and I am following the tutorial [by Patrick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ&t=30486s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org) based on the [project](https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/smartcontract-lottery)

I have my code here at  :https://github.com/shashankvivek/blockchain/tree/main/smartLottery_contract_revisited

whenever I run my project using deploy script, I am getting

```
Funded link to contract
  LinkToken.transfer confirmed   Block: 31016770   Gas used: 52458 (90.91%)

  File "C:\Users\snitw\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "C:\Users\snitw\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 103, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File ".\scripts\deploy_lottery.py", line 52, in main
    end_lottery()
  File ".\scripts\deploy_lottery.py", line 43, in end_lottery
    end_tx = lottery.endLottery({"from": account})
  File "C:\Users\snitw\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 1710, in __call__
    return self.transact(*args)
  File "C:\Users\snitw\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 1583, in transact
    return tx["from"].transfer(
  File "C:\Users\snitw\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 644, in transfer
    receipt, exc = self._make_transaction(
  File "C:\Users\snitw\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 727, in _make_transaction
    raise VirtualMachineError(e) from None
  File "C:\Users\snitw\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\exceptions.py", line 93, in __init__
    raise ValueError(str(exc)) from None
ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'The execution failed due to an exception.'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually.
```

It seems like a gas issue when I look at the error , and specifically on below line:

> end_tx = lottery.endLottery({"from": account})

but I have enough ETH and Gas

[image]

Took my keys from https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf-contracts/v1/ , running solidity 0.6.6

I am running

> brownie run .\scripts\deploy_lottery.py --network kovan

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue when my contract itself didn't have any 'Link' token.

I'm also doing the tutorial and looking at your code, I believe the issue is in the fund_with_link line (line 41 of deploy_lottery.py). It should be

```
tx = fund_with_link(lottery.address)
```

instead of

```
tx = fund_with_link(lottery)
```

You need to fund the 'address' of the contract lottery - as it appears in the repo https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/smartcontract-lottery/blob/main/scripts/helpful_scripts.py